# SignalR active/passive failover setup

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr, load-balancing, failover

I have two SignalR servers sitting behind HaProxy loadbalancer with configured active/passive configuration.

At a time, all requests are forwarded to one node. Let's say, `node1` is the active one and `node2` is hot&ready but doesn't receive any traffic from LB because `node1` is online.

When users open web-page SignalR clients get connected to `node1` through LB. Let's say we have one client connected to our server.

When `node1` goes down, HaProxy switches traffic to `node2` and connected clients through SignalR detect that connection was dropped and try to do a reconnect call. Although `node2` is up and running, clients get error for reconnection as following:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.0.11.88:12000/signalr/reconnect?transport=webSockets&messageId=s-0%2C12A&clientProtocol=1.5&myparam1=1&myparam2=6&token=6372bdbd1ca64f06aa52362a6913bdd8&connectionToken=lxqeSwxAu756vF0TwhXCFzb0ZMHraRocsx7jS2A%2F%2Ben0vgtfI9Fid47oLiKg4KnX3E5eFKwwaezv4JSPbrsLr3C%2FmTGS8Ev3WLgAUZcbAjvlf9VHYsxbEcYV7Z09rHEH&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22gamewindow%22%7D%5D&tid=7' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

When exploring output in visual studio I found these error logs:

`` SignalR.HubDispatcher Information: 0 : Failed to process connectionToken lxqeSwxAu756vF0TwhXCFzb0ZMHraRocsx7jS2A/+en0vgtfI9Fid47oLiKg4KnX3E5eFKwwaezv4JSPbrsLr3C/mTGS8Ev3WLgAUZcbAjvlf9VHYsxbEcYV7Z09rHEH: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
   at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.DataProtectionProviderProtectedData.Unprotect(String protectedValue, String purpose)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.TryGetConnectionId(HostContext context, String connectionToken, String& connectionId, String& message, Int32& statusCode) ``

In scenario when reconnection attempt hits the same server to which client was connected in the first place everything works fine even if the server-application got completely restarted.

Any insight on this error or some best practices on how to implement failover solution for SignalR would be much appreciated.

Also I do know about backplane scale-out approach, but I believe that issue above will be present there as well.

Answer (score 1):

After some research, found fix.

**Why did I get CryptographicException** : SignalR uses some cryptography to do security things with connectionId. For hashing it uses `machineKey` which is by default silently generated by IIS and injected into `web.config` in runtime. So my two servers were getting two different `machineKey` configurations and that's why SignalR client couldn't reconnect to `node2` but reconnecting to `node1` was successfull even after it's restart.

**The fix** was to disable automatic `machineKey` generation in IIS(there is a section in IIS Manager with the same name) and provide the same `machineKey` config for both nodes. Once this was done, SignalR client reconnected to `node2` without any problems when `node1` got disconnected.

Also would like to mention that `machineKey` is a set of two keys and it's not a random string and has it's own format. Shouldn't be a problem to find out how to generate it once you know that you need to :)